# Prove $\sum_{k=0}^{n}k*p_n(k)=n!$

Tags: combinatorics, summation

I simplified the above problem to

Prove$$\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-k}\frac{(-1)^i}{(k-1)!\,i!}\right)=1$$

Here $p_n(k)$ denotes number of permutations of $\{1,2,\dots ,n\}$ such that we have k fixed points.

How to proceed?

Comment: That sounds like the reverse of simplification.

Comment: Should the inner sum go from $0$ to $k-1$?

Answer (score 5):

There are exactly $n!$ permutations of $\{1, 2, \dots, n\}$, and the equation is just classifying each permutation with respect to number of fixed points.

Comment: Sorry I missed a $k$ in the equation in the title. Does your argument still hold with the $k$?

Answer (score 1):

**Answer for the new question.** We can adopt the indicator function technique:

Let $S_n$ be the set of permutations on $\{1,\cdots,n\}$. Then for each $\sigma\in S_n$, the number of fixed points of $\sigma$ can be written as $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbf{1}_{\{\sigma(i)=i\}}$. So

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}k p_n(k)
=\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbf{1}_{\{\sigma(i)=i\}}
=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\mathbf{1}_{\{\sigma(i)=i\}}
=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(n-1)!=n!.$$

Answer (score 0):

You have **changed** the problem in the edit.

You can rewrite
$$\sum_{k=0}^n kp_k(n)$$
as
$$\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}|\textrm{fix}(\sigma)|$$
where $\textrm{fix}(\sigma)$ is the set of fixed points of $\sigma$.
By Burnside's lemma, this equals $n!M$ where $M$ is the number
of orbits of $S_n$ on its natural action on $\{1,\ldots,n\}$.
But $M=1$.

Comment: Is there any more elementary way? I Dont think I'll be allowed to use burnside's lemma without proving it